# How should I design a "Create Project" wizard?

Tags: programming, design

I'm working on a project that needs to have a "Create Project" wizard, the one I made doesn't-look-very-elementary. I found no information on wizards in elementary HIG, and I am not sure how to make it fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [The Wizard Anti-Pattern](http://stef.thewalter.net/installer-anti-pattern.html) by Stef Walter. It's part of the "See Also" in the [Design Philosophy](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines#design-philosophy) section of the HIG.

The TL;DR is to avoid wizards at all cost. Get as much info automatically as you can, make solid opinionated design/engineering decisions for most other things, and only ask for things that are really essential to ask about.